# Wiremock admin api security

Tags: wiremock

Is there a way to prevent anonymous access to the wiremock admin api? I'm hoping there is an option to specify an apikey but i'm unable to find it. I am running wiremock in standalone mode.

Comment: What's your specific use case that you'd need to prevent anonymous access?

Comment: Hi.To restrict the ability to reset the stubs and requests either maliciously or accidentally. Also to restrict access to any potentially sensitive data in the stubs or request headers.

I see mocklab has implemented admin api security:
https://www.mocklab.io/docs/security/